# XML Safe URLEncoding?

Tags: .net, asp.net, xml

How do I encode an URL that will be "xml-safe" where the ampersand(&) in the querystring will not corrupt the XML?

For Instance:

www.somedomain.com/SomePage.aspx?SomeParam=SomeValue&SomeParam2=SomeVal

Comment: If would help you specified why?  I can't think why someone who isn't doing something ill-advised (such as building XML with string concatenation) would need to worry about this.  I'm not saying that you are doing that just that it would help to know that you aren't doing that or something similarly strange.

Comment: I'm working with an API that accepts xml and one of the fields is an url.  I need to specify dynamic parameters in the URL that is being passed in the document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is to encode the URL just like any other text in the document. You won't go wrong if you replace characters as follows:

```
& -> &amp;
' -> &apos;
" -> &quot;
< -> &lt;
> -> &gt;
```

(and anybody reading the document with a conforming parser will get the correct, i.e. unencoded, text back).

However, I would echo Anthony's comment: why do you think you need to worry about this? Any sensible XML writing system should take the text you want to represent and do the encoding itself (just like a parser will undo the encoding). Your application should only have to deal with the unencoded text and it should rely on an XML writing library to deal with character encoding and preserving well-formedness. Otherwise you risk [being called a bozo](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/producing-xml/). It looks like [XmlTextWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkee9k2s%28VS.71%29.aspx) is the .net API that makes all the necessary changes.

Comment: I was using an custom TextWriter class to process the serialization of my class.  When I switched it to a XMLTextWriter the XML serialized correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The [AntiXSS](http://antixss.codeplex.com) library has an XmlEncode method which you could use.