# How to add special characters like & > in XML file using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml

I am generating XML using Javascript. It works fine if there are no special characters in the XML. Otherwise, it will generate this message: "invalid xml".

I tried to replace some special characters, like:

```
xmlData=xmlData.replaceAll(">","&gt;");
xmlData=xmlData.replaceAll("&","&amp;");
//but it doesn't work.
```

For example:

```
<category label='ARR Builders & Developers'>
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327663/xml-safe-urlencoding

Comment: If you want to generate XML, then use an XML library, don't try to mash together strings. That way lies madness.

Comment: `replaceAll()` is not available by default in JavaScript, you'll have to use `replace()` with a global regular expression unless you want to extend `String.prototype` to contain `replaceAll`.

Comment: You must replace the `&` first, otherwise the result would be something like `&amp;gt;` which is not good.

Comment: I already tried .replace("&","&amp;") method, it replace the & with &amp; but even xml generate error when running

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider [generating the XML using DOM methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_create_a_DOM_tree).  For example:

```javascript
var c = document.createElement("category");
c.setAttribute("label", "ARR Builders & Developers");
var s = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(c);
s; // => "<category label=\"ARR Builder &amp; Developers\"></category>"
```

This strategy should avoid the XML entity escaping problems you mention but might have some cross-browser issues.

Answer (score 2):

This will do the replacement in JavaScript:

```javascript
xml = xml.replace(/</g, "&lt;");
xml = xml.replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
```

This uses [regular expression literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_Regular_Expression) to replace all less than and greater than symbols with their escaped equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript comes with a powerful `replace()` method for string objects.

In general - and basic - terms, it works this way:

```
var myString = yourString.replace([regular expression or simple string], [replacement string]);
```

The first argument to `.replace()` method is the portion of the original string that you wish to replace. It can be represented by either a plain string object (even literal) or a regular expression.

The regular expression is obviously the most powerful way to select a substring.

The second argument is the string object (even literal) that you want to provide as a replacement.

In your case, the replacement operation should look as follows:

```
xmlData=xmlData.replace(/&/g,"&amp;");
xmlData=xmlData.replace(/>/g,"&gt;");
//this time it should work.
```

Notice the first replacement operation is the ampersand, as if you should try to replace it later you would screw up pre-existing well-quoted entities for sure, just as `"&amp;gt;"`.

In addition, pay attention to the regex 'g' flag, as with it the replacement will take place all throughout your text, not only on the first match.

I used regular expressions, but for simple replacements like these also plain strings would be a perfect fit.

You can find a complete reference for `String.replace()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: The regular expressions used here will only replace the _first_ instance of & and > respectively. You need to use the global flag to make the regex match _all_ instances, e.g. `/&/g`.

Comment: @jakeclarkson: you are right. I'll specify this in my edit. Thank you.

Comment: I think @maerics has the most structured and "well-mannered" solution, even if constructing XML with simple strings can be fairly easier (but often more inclined to headaches, for complex structures).